# Design strategies to generalize control

Tags: c#, .net

I have a GUI control that I need to generalize so it can be used in different situations and I need suggestions. Let me give you some background first. I have a model that stores all my data for a specific application. I access and set the data points through properties in this model.

Right now I am passing the instance of the model to the GUI control and there the client can set/reset/read in the control two specific pieces of data (in the code I am using the properties). That is all good, but now the model has 3  more  sets of these two "columns" (six new fields) that also need to be manipulated by the same control in other 3 new different situations. Obviously I don't want to create 3 more copies of this same control (yes, extensibility was not considered when the control was first designed, I know, I know). So, I tried passing a reference to the properties in the control constructor which of course does not work (compiler error: A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter). So, my question is, what would be a good design strategy in this case? How can I generalize this control so it can be reused and it can set/edit these other properties in the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, why don't you use a property of dictionary type that allows you to set various number of properties (with a key value string for property name and value for value of property)

Comment: You mean passing a dictionary with the name of the property I want to set in the model? Or passing the property name and a reference in the value of the dictionary?

Comment: I mean the second choice (because your properties can be different class).If you have always only two fields in different situation, you can use two fixed fields with generic name.If you think that as for context, it is possible to have different number of fields, use dictionary. You can also think to use Workflow Foundation, which allow you to make custom activities.this technology is useful when you want to design your business model (I have worked with).

Comment: Well you gave me an idea of something I had forgotten... System.Reflection.PropertyInfo. That lets you dynamically set any property of that object I want. I just need to give it the property names (which I know) and problem solved... I think :) I will test this and post back if it works.